# Sending a List of record along with the associated record to a view in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to a send a list of Students to a view along with the associated teacher and display
the teacher details along with the list of students in the view .i don't want the teacher details to repeat for every for every student.Whats the best way to achieve this ?

```
public class Teacher
{
 public int Id {get;set}
 public string Name {get;set;}
 public virtual ICollection<Student> student {get ; set;}
}

public class Student 
{

 public int Id {get;set}
 public string Name {get;set;}
 public virtual Teacher teacher{get ; set;}
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what data you want in the view? Is it all the students that belong to a single teacher? Or does this view show multiple teachers?

Comment: the list of the students and single teacher associated the student

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to type your View to your `Teacher` model:

```
@model Teacher

<h1>@Model.Name</h1>
```

Now you just need to loop through the students collection in your model

```
@foreach(var student in @Model.Students){
     <p>@student.Name</p>
}
```

Comment: the foreach loop also load the teacher details associated ryt ?

Comment: The foreach iterates over collections. Since `Teacher` has a property that is a collection of students, you can simply iterate over each item in the collection and render the details you want.

Comment: i want the teacher details to load only once and not for every student .... say there 200000 records ... that may unnecessarily load data of the teacher

Comment: That is what this code is doing. You are typing to a single `Teacher` entity, and then displaying its `Student`s.